# Amazon AWS IPv6 Http Request --> EAFNOSUPPORT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ipv6

Lambda AWS Funktion With NodeJs 8.10.
Doing the Reuest with "google.de" works fine und a get the Status Code 200.
Calling with the IPv6 Adress I get an Error.
The IPv6 Link works fine, when I try it on my Smartphone/Laptop Browser

```
    var url = "http://[2a02:XXXXX:XXXXX:XXXXX:XXXX:855c]:3000/lumos/1/1";
     //var url = "http://www.google.de";
    var http = require('http');
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
        sendResult(responseHeader, requestToken, "ON");
    }).on('error', function(e) {
         console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
         sendResult(responseHeader, requestToken, "OFF");
    });
```

Error:

```
2018-11-13T01:47:44.626Z    1d27e34c-e6e6-11e8-a01c-e158231ddd60    Got error: connect EAFNOSUPPORT 2a02:XXXXX:XXXXX:XXXXX:XXXX:855c:3000 - Local (undefined:undefined)
```

Comment: firstly always tried to run local machine because some time its happen if version is different.

Comment: It's part of a Alexa Skill, so I have to develop in the AWS, I guess.
Or is there a possibility to connect my Alexa to a local NodeJs?

Answer (score 0):

There are more Users with the same Problem in the aws forum of amazon.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=771838&tstart=0

At this Time, AWS Lambda does not support IPv6 Access.
Workaround could be gateway...
Have a look at:
https://www.sixxs.net/tools/gateway/